# Firebase Cloud Functions Getting user uid not working from unity

Tags: javascript, c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently working on implementing a matchmaking system for my game using Firebase Cloud Functions. The goal is to assign players to matches and prevent them from impersonating others. To achieve this, I'm trying to use the Cloud Function to obtain the user's UID and store it securely.

However, I'm encountering issues with the authentication process in the Cloud Function. The user is authenticated in the app, but when I call the cloud function, I can't retrieve their UID. I would like to be able to obtain it from there to prevent the user from impersonating someone else.

I get this error on server:
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')
at /workspace/index.js:33:29
at fixedLen (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/https.js:118:31)
at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:467:32
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Also if I send data to server, on server data always is undefined.

```cs
        // Prepare data to send to the Cloud Function
        Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        data["idToken"] = idToken;

        // Call Function
        var callableTask = function.CallAsync(data);
```

```js
  const userToken = data.idToken;
```

Unity Code:

```cs
    public void CallFuncions ()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CallMatchmakingFunction());
    }

    IEnumerator CallMatchmakingFunction()
    {
        var function = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance.GetHttpsCallable("matchmaking");

        // Call Function
        var task = function.CallAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted);

        if (task.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error: {task.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            var result = (string)task.Result.Data;
            Debug.Log($"Firebase Result: {result}");
        }
    }
```

Server Code:

```js
exports.matchmaking = onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const matchesRef = database.ref("matches");

  const userToken = context.auth.uid;
  /*
  // This works to get Username, buy I need user UID
  const displayName = (await admin.auth()
      .getUser("ZC96qyLzBzOLKgElVkcIAiClwau1")).displayName;
      */

  // Try to find match
  matchesRef
      .orderByChild("status")
      .equalTo("waiting")
      .limitToFirst(1)
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          // Joining match
          const matchId = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];
          joinMatch(matchId);
          return { uid: userToken };
        } else {
          // Creating match
          createMatch();
          return { uid: userToken };
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error en el matchmaking:", error);
      });
});
```

How can I get the user UID?

I have tried using `onRequest`, `onCall`, `auth.userId` and `auth.uid`, but none of them seem to work. The only way that works is by passing the UID from the client, which could potentially compromise the security of the application.

Comment: "I can't retrieve their UID" and "none of them seem to work" are hard to help with. If you `console.log(userToken)` what does it output? Please edit your question to show the updated code, and its output.